# TornadoFX - Creating a MVP Design

Tags: javafx, kotlin, mvp, tornadofx

Hello I'm new to using TornadoFX and I was wondering what the best design for a MVP structure would be using TornadoFX?

In MVP the view:

-> would delegate all events such as button clicking to a function in the presenter

-> does not interact with the model

Here are some of the rough prototype ideas:

```
abstract class AbstractPresenter<View : tornadofx.View> : Controller() {

var view: View by Delegates.notNull()

fun attachView(view: View) {
    this.view = view;
 }
}
```

I create a presenter which attaches itself to a AbstractView:

```
abstract class AbstractView<out Presenter : AbstractPresenter<*>> : View() {

abstract val presenter: Presenter

}
```

Now using it in a example:

```
class SampleTestView: AbstractView<SampleTestPresenter>() {

override val presenter: SampleTestPresenter by inject()
override val root: AnchorPane by fxml()

val testButton: Button by fxid()

init {
    presenter.attachView(this)
    testButton.setOnAction { presenter.doSomething() }
   }

}
```

The Sample Presenter:

```
class SampleTestPresenter: AbstractPresenter<SampleWindowView>() {

fun doSomething() {
    println("did it")
}

}
```

Is this a decent implementation of the MVP pattern using TornadoFX?

***EDIT***

Made some changes:

```
class SampleWindowView : View() {
override val root: AnchorPane by fxml()
val presenter : SampleWindowViewPresenter by inject()

val button:Button by fxid()

init {
    button.setOnAction {  presenter.handleButtonClick() }
  }
}


class SampleWindowViewPresenter : Controller() {

val sampleView: SampleWindowView by inject()

fun handleButtonClick() {
    println("clicked")
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the abstract classes? TornadoFX's built in `View` and `Controller` classes work great for MVC, MVP, or even MVVM (despite being named Controller).

Comment: Also, `View`s are singletons as well, so you can just put `val view: SimpleTestView by inject()` in your presenter. I'm not sure how important the onViewAttached function is.

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom Oh I see I did not know that views are singletons. The abstract classes are there to enforce the idea that for every View, there is a Presenter attached to it. I've made changes to the main post. Feel free to add any suggestions to it

Comment: If you want to enforce it, you can go definitely use the abstract classes (though the generics could probably be done better; I'm not an expert on generics). I think the latter one feels cleaner though.

Comment: Also, SO isn't a great place for questions like "Does this look good?" It's often hard to post an answer beyond yes or no that isn't a discussion. For those kinds of questions, the TornadoFX slack channel is great: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/messages/tornadofx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the discussion above, you can simply do:

```
class SampleTestView : View() {
    val presenter: SampleTestPresenter by inject()

    override val root: AnchorPane by fxml()
    val testButton: Button by fxid()

    init {
        testButton.setOnAction { presenter.doSomething() }
    }
}

class SampleTestPresenter : Controller() {
    val view: SampleTestView by inject()

    fun doSomething() {
        println("Did the thing")
    }
}
```

If you want to ensure the view has a presenter, you could create an abstract view and have all your views extend from it:

```
abstract class AbstractView<Presenter : Controller> : View() {
    abstract val presenter: Presenter
}
```

Comment: Thanks for summarizing the discussion. I'll definitely use the abstract classes but I'm still not sure how the generics could be improved. I would use Presenter : AbstractPresenter<*> or would using Presenter : Controller be better? Also If I wanted to ensure the presenter has the view, this can be done the same way as I presented in the original post right

Comment: Sure, but it seems a little weird to me conceptually to ensure the presenter has a view since you can't use generics to force the presenter and the view to be paired.

Comment: But I don't know your use case, so if it works for you, go for it.